# CSS div overlay tag works fine in Chrome on desktop, but not in Chrome on Android

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

I have a simple overlay `<div>` tag which puts some text on top of an image. Here is the HTML code:

```html
<div class="single_image">
  <div id="example-1" class="thumbs">
    <a href="images/photos/01/DSC05689.jpg">
      <img src="images/m1.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="images/photos/01/DSC05690.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/photos/01/DSC05692.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/photos/01/DSC05693.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/photos/01/DSC05694.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/photos/01/DSC05705.jpg"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="overlay">Tap to view</div>
</div>
```

This is what the code looks like in Chrome browser on a desktop machine:

[image: On desktop]

But if I open the page in Chrome on Android, the text falls down below the image and this is what I get:

[image: On Android device]

This is my CSS:

```css
.overlay {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Stupid question, but why are your html and your css in different snippets?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have been an issue with browser cache. If I opened the page on an incognito tab on Android, it worked as expected.